# Convert Powershell output to a Markdown file

Tags: powershell, scripting, type-conversion, markdown

I have the following code:

```
$xmlFile        = 'C:\Users\kraer\Desktop\bom.xml'

[xml]$xml = Get-Content $xmlFile


    $xml.bom.components.component | ForEach-Object {
        $finalObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Name'      = $_.name
        'Version'   = $_.version
        'License'   = $_.licenses.license.id
    }
    Write-Output $finalObject
}
```

Now I would like to convert my $finalObject to a MarkDown Table. Are there any possibilities here?

For another question I received this answer but right now it doesn't work for my code.

```
function ConvertTo-MarkDownTable {
    [CmdletBinding()] param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeLine = $True)] $InputObject
    )
    Begin { $Init = $True }
    Process {
        if ( $Init ) {
            $Init = $False
            $_.PSObject.Properties.Name -Join '|'
            $_.PSObject.Properties.ForEach({ '-' }) -Join '|'
        }
        $_.PSObject.Properties.Value -Join '|'
    }
}
```

Do you have another solution?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You are probably calling like `ConvertTo-MarkDownTable $finalObject`?  Change all the `$_` to `$InputObject` inside the ConvertTo-MarkDownTable function

Comment: "it doesn't work for my code." - please show us _how_ you're calling (and passing arguments to) `ConvertTo-MarkDownTable`

Comment: sorry I was quite busy the last few days. Your answer has helped me a lot thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing the contents of your bom.xml, you might try this slightly adapted version of the function:

```
function ConvertTo-MarkDownTable {
    [CmdletBinding()] param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)] 
        $InputObject
    )
    Begin { 
        $headersDone = $false
        $pattern = '(?<!\\)\|'  # escape every '|' unless already escaped
    }
    Process {
        if (!$headersDone) {
            $headersDone = $true
            # output the header line and below that a dashed line
            # -replace '(?<!\\)\|', '\|' escapes every '|' unless already escaped
            '|{0}|' -f (($_.PSObject.Properties.Name -replace $pattern, '\|') -join '|')
            '|{0}|' -f (($_.PSObject.Properties.Name -replace '.', '-') -join '|')
        }
        '|{0}|' -f (($_.PsObject.Properties.Value -replace $pattern, '\|') -join '|')
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
# load the xml from file
$xml= New-Object System.XML.XMLDocument
$xml.Load('C:\Users\kraer\Desktop\bom.xml')

$finalObject = $xml.bom.components.component | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Name'    = $_.name
        'Version' = $_.version
        'License' = $_.licenses.license.id
    }
}
# convert to markdown
$finalObject | ConvertTo-MarkDownTable
```

P.S. `$_.licenses.license.id` might be wrong, because it looks like `licenses` is an **array** of licences. You would probably want to do something like this here:

```
($_.licenses | ForEach-Object { $_.license.id }) -join '; '
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer but it doesn't create a markdown table.

Comment: @bobby17jones Yeah, sorry, my bad.. I have edited the answer now.