# How should I do Powershell error handling?

Tags: powershell, logging, error-handling, save

I have the following code:

```
function main {
    #get all content
    [XML]$xml = Get-Content $XMLfile

    $finalObject = $xml.bom.components.component | ForEach-Object {
        $lic = $_.licenses.license.id
        $url = $_.licenses.license.url
        $web = ($_.externalReferences.reference | Where-Object { $_.type -eq 'website' }).url
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Name'    = if ($web) { '[{0}]({1})' -f $_.Name, $web } elseif ($url) { '[{0}]({1})' -f $_.Name, $url } elseif (!$url) { $_.Name } else {'Unknown'}
            'Version' = $_.version
            'License' = if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($lic)) { 'Unknown' } else { $lic }
        }
    }
    # convert to markdown
    $finalObject | ConvertTo-MarkDownTable  | Out-File -FilePath $saveMdFile

}
```

Now I want to do error handling with powershell. For example, if the XML is not present or if it cannot be saved I would like to have error logs. The logs should then be saved separately in a file. I have defined them as follows:

```
function main {
    #get all content
    [XML]$xml = Get-Content $XMLfile

    Write-Log -Message "No file was found: $($xmlfile)" -Level Info -Path $logpath

    $finalObject = $xml.bom.components.component | ForEach-Object {
        $lic = $_.licenses.license.id
        $url = $_.licenses.license.url
        $web = ($_.externalReferences.reference | Where-Object { $_.type -eq 'website' }).url
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Name'    = if ($web) { '[{0}]({1})' -f $_.Name, $web } elseif ($url) { '[{0}]({1})' -f $_.Name, $url } elseif (!$url) { $_.Name } else {'Unknown'}
            'Version' = $_.version
            'License' = if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($lic)) { 'Unknown' } else { $lic }
        }
    }
    # convert to markdown
    $finalObject | ConvertTo-MarkDownTable  | Out-File -FilePath $saveMdFile

    Write-Log -Message "No path was found: $($xmlfile)" -Level Info -Path $logpath
}
```

My logs do not work so far and the file is also not saved when an error occurs. Does anyone have a clue how I can fix this problem?

Comment: May be `try` `catch`?

Comment: You do not explain where variables `$XMLfile` and `$saveMdFile` come from, nor where you got your `Write-Log` function. If you mean to catch an error when `Get-Content $XMLfile` fails because the file is not found, use [Test-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path) first.

Comment: Where does `$logpath` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use the `Write-Log` function from [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ScriptLogger/1.1.1/Content/Functions%5CWrite-Log.ps1) and the `ConvertTo-MarkDownTable` from your earlier questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69016795/9898643) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69011926/9898643), all you need to do is make sure the variables `$XMLfile`, `$saveMdFile` and `$logpath` are known and valid in your function main.

One way of doing that is by using [Test-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path) and personally I would set these variables as optional parameters with default paths so you can either accept these defaults or call the function with different paths.

Something like this:

```
function main {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 0)]
        [string]$xmlFile = 'C:\Users\kraer\Desktop\bom.xml',

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 1)]
        [string]$logpath = 'C:\Users\kraer\Desktop\siteinfo.log',

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 2)]
        [string]$saveMdFile = 'C:\Users\kraer\Desktop\siteinfo.md'
    )

    # try and write to the log
    try {
        Write-Log -Message "Logging started: '$((Get-Date).ToString())'" -Level Info -Path $logpath -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Error from 'Write-Log': $($_.Exception.Message)"
        return   # exit the function
    }

    # check if the XML file can be found
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $xmlFile -PathType Leaf)) {
        Write-Warning "Xml file '$xmlFile' not found"
        Write-Log -Message "No file was found: '$xmlfile'" -Level Error -Path $logpath
        return   # exit the function
    }

    # get all content. better use this, so you will get the encoding right
    $xml = [System.XML.XMLDocument]::new()
    $xml.Load($xmlFile)
    # assuming this does what you want
    $finalObject = $xml.bom.components.component | ForEach-Object {
        $lic = $_.licenses.license.id
        $url = $_.licenses.license.url
        $web = ($_.externalReferences.reference | Where-Object { $_.type -eq 'website' }).url
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Name'    = if ($web) { '[{0}]({1})' -f $_.Name, $web } elseif ($url) { '[{0}]({1})' -f $_.Name, $url } elseif (!$url) { $_.Name } else {'Unknown'}
            'Version' = $_.version
            'License' = if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($lic)) { 'Unknown' } else { $lic }
        }
    }
    # convert to markdown
    try {
        $finalObject | ConvertTo-MarkDownTable | Set-Content -Path $saveMdFile -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Could not write to file '$saveMdFile'"
        Write-Log -Message "Could not write to file '$saveMdFile'" -Level Error -Path $logpath
    }
}
```